# Xamarin Forms Android - EnableForegroundDispatch

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am trying to adapt a version of this demo app on Github for my own usage: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/NfcSample 
The problem is that on an NDEF formatted tag the app can write to tags consecutively but when a format is required the write only works once. If my phone is locked and then unlocked with the app running and it comes to the foreground it works once again. I think it is something to do with 'EnableForegroundDispatch' but I am not sure.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks
Paul.